# Is there a method to know substitute to the run button on IntelliJ for Command Line

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there any way that we can find out what command actually we have to run on a command line window such that it gives the exact output as it would when we hit the run Button [image] on IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: Mostly try looking for how to find the `mainClass` of a module/project. While you do run a command from prompt it would ideally start from a mainClass of either your code directly(when you execute a single class with main method) or framework specific ABCApplication class that determines the entry point of the application.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the run button in IntelliJ, the actual command that it ran is printed at the top of the IntelliJ console. For me, it looks like this:

[image: Console first line]

If you click on the green highlighted area, it expands to show the full command line that was run.